# The partial differential equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} -c\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + ax^2 \frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x^2} =0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have been confronted with a partial differential equation of the following form
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} -c\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}  +  ax^2 \frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x^2}   = 0 
\end{equation}
with two of the boundary conditions being $u(x,0)=0$ and $u(0,t)=0$. Of course I also need a third boundary condition to get a unique solution. Is it possible to solve this and get a somewhat analytical solution. I tried Laplace transform but that didn't seem to help much.

Comment: did you try seperation of variables?

Comment: No, since I have a dirichlet condition for as an initial condition.

Comment: what difference does this make?

Comment: I will only get the trivial solution.

Comment: why is that? this is interesting

Comment: Because the solution is either not separable, or my modelling is wrong and the trivial solution is the only solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52550/discussion-between-freelunch-and-tired).